# Conditional form in the contact detail section

Tags: contact

We use salesforce for some projects at work, and I believe we do it on a very basic level. The whole system was created before me but I find it to be very inefficient and I would like to improve it but I have absolutely no knowledge about salesforce, coding, and googling didn't help (maybe because I don't know the correct terms and couldn't explain the issue).

The situation is that in the contact detail section we have a lot of different subsections and questions related to answers to previous answers. That's why I would like to make it like a conditional form. Because what happens now is that I have a big general question and then a lot of smaller questions for any answer to this general question, so I will only answer one out of them and many are left blank. I don't know if this is clear, so here's an imaginary example where every line is a new question in the form:

- invitation status: accepted/declined/no response
- coming alone or with someone (only relevant if the answer is "accepted")
- time of arrival (only relevant if the answer is "accepted")
- decline reason (only relevant if the answer is "declined")
- follow-up sent? (only relevant if the answer is "no response")

Instead, I would like to have only the first question visible, and then depending on the answer, the other questions will pop up.

Is it possible to do it in the contact details section on salesforce? Hope this was clear and I will really appreciate answers with lots of detail as once again I am very new to this :)

Comment: If you are using salesforce OOTB page layout then conditional rendering is not possible. If it is lightning copmonent/ vf page can you share the code?

Comment: I think you can use Dynamic Forms of Standard Salesforce (no need to do custom code). Here a link: https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-dynamic-forms-overview-deep-dive-tutorial/

Comment: Dynamic Forms for Contact is Winter 23